# U-SQL Extracting files wrong format

Tags: u-sql, extractor

this is my first post/question about U-SQL
My process extract from Azure Data Lake Storage huge files data.
My problems is one of the files has wrong structure (one field less than expected) and is crashing my process.

I would like to manage exceptions, keep process running and inform which file has been rejected or with errors.

I know about parameter ( silent : true ), I am just looking for a robust solution for production environment...If I just skip one file I am loosing millions of transactions.

**Below is my extract code:**

@Source =

```
    EXTRACT [RouteVariant] string,
            [StageNumber] string,
            [StopNumber] string,
            [TransactionTime] string,                
            [TicketClass] string,
            [TransactionDate] int,
            [FareValue] double
    FROM @"/Files/Transactions/{*}.csv"
    USING Extractors.Text(delimiter : ';' );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that some files may come without a field, you could mark that column as *Null* when you extract.

For example, let's say TicketClass was the dimension that may not appear:

```
EXTRACT [RouteVariant] string,
        [StageNumber] string,
        [StopNumber] string,
        [TransactionTime] string,                
        [TicketClass] string?,
        [TransactionDate] int,
        [FareValue] double
FROM @"/Files/Transactions/{*}.csv"
USING Extractors.Text(delimiter : ';' );
```

With the interrogation mark you allow that dimension to be *Null* if it doesn't appear during the extraction.

Comment: Thanks jonordona. When csv file has 8 columns instead of 9 expected, I have an error. My idea is rise an exception and process other files with expected number of columns.